# How does a list gets compared to another list?

Tags: python, list

In the first part, I have 2 lists which are equal but unsorted. When I check whether they are equal, the print function returns "False", which makes sense.

```
listx1, listx2=[9, 7, 5, 3], [3, 5, 7, 9] 
print(listx1 == listx2)     #returns False
```

When I sort this list, the print function returns "True". Till this point I understood:

```
print(listx1.sort() == listx2.sort())   #returns True
```

Now, I use 2 unequal lists and compare them. This time also, print function returns False, which makes sense.

```
listx3, listx4 =[5, 3, 2, 7], [3, 5, 7, 9]
print(listx3 == listx4)              #returns False
```

But shouldn't I get "False" while checking their equality, even after sorting them (considering that they consist of unequal elements)? Here, I am confused because after sorting listx3 and listx4, the print function returns "True". (as per the code written below)

```
print(listx3.sort() == listx4.sort())     #returns True
```

Where am I wrong in my understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listx1.sort()` sorts the list in place, and returns `None`, like all functions and methods that don't have a specific return value. So your test:

```
listx1.sort() == listx2.sort()
```

is actually `None == None`, which is True.

What you should do to compare the sorted lists is:

```
listx1.sort()
listx2.sort()
list1 == list2
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.sort()` method operates on the list in-place and returns nothing. The `sorted()` built-in function returns a new sorted copy of the list. If you use:

```
sorted(listx3) == sorted(listx4)
```

you'll get the answer you expect.

In cases like this, testing the individual pieces of the code in the Python interpreter would help you figure out what is happening. For example, if you `print(listx3.sort())` you would see that it prints `None`.